# What is the nature of the cross product? It is vectorised as a single vector and appears to lose what we seemingly define as it's rotation.

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product

In physics, if properties have the same units, they can be added, although this isn't always physically descriptive, it can be done. I understand this is because the same units have the same span. More often than not, in math, units are withheld for generalization of values that have units, (coordinate space can be length or angular).

So what happens if I evaluate
$$ \vec{i}\times\vec{j} - \vec{k}$$
Without a second thought we get $\vec{0}$, but if we ask a different but similar question where it's obvious one of the vectors represents rotation in a way the other does not
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F}(\vec{r}) + \vec{F}(\vec{r})$$ I don't expect to be able to say anything about the answer, but what does it mean that these values can be added? We know the curl of F represents the rotation of F, but without units, it seems that nothing stops one from adding these quantities, so what should they mean?

Comment: Note that there's a very subtle implicit conversion going on here, with a very important consequence - the expressions you've written _aren't_ coordinate-invariant. In particular, cross products transform differently under transformations of the coordinate system than vectors do, so while you can _write_ expressions like the ones you've written, you can't write them in a fashion that isn't implicitly tied to your coordinates.

Comment: (I wrote a little bit about this at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62318/origin-of-the-dot-and-cross-product/62370#62370 , though that doesn't really talk as much about the behavior under transformations as it could.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It might not have been extensive on transformations, it did clear up that I can just add vectors and cross products willy nilly just because they share notation and it's convenient to call them vectors.