# Inner Product Spaces and representing the square of a norm as a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, intuition, inner-products

While trying to understand the motivation of studying the inner product (see [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138924/how-to-motivate-the-axioms-for-the-inner-product)) I came across the blog entry [here](https://jmanton.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/understanding-real-and-complex-valued-inner-products/). Essentially the argument made is that norms are important because they impart geometry to a vector space. Inner product spaces provide "nice" norms in the sense that the square of the norm is quadratic and this is desirable in optimization.

Can someone explain what is meant by the square of the norm being quadratic? The author says that this means that the square of the norm comes from a bilinear form. But then I don't perceive the reason for that bilinear form to be symmetric.

Also how exactly is the square of the norm being quadratic helpful in optimization?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the symmetry of the bilinear form: any bilinear form on a vector space $V$ can be decomposed as a sum of a symmetric part and an anti-symmetric one in a unique way, given by
$$B(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\left(B(x,y)+B(y,x)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(B(x,y)-B(y,x)\right)=B_s(x,y)+B_a(x,y).$$
Now if you want to define a norm based on this you find that
$$\|x\|^2=B(x,x)=B_s(x,x)+B_a(x,x)=B_s(x,x).$$

So if you know the norm you can only recover the "symmetric part" of the bilinear form that induced it; and any norm induced by a bilinear form is induced by a symmetric one. Moreover, in that case the symmetric bilinear form is unique, and can be determined by the following formulas (this is the polarization identity mentioned in the blog post you linded to):

$$B(u, v) = \frac{\lVert u\rVert^2 + \lVert v\rVert^2 - \lVert u - v\rVert^2}{2} = \frac{\lVert u + v\rVert^2 - \lVert u\rVert^2 - \lVert v\rVert^2}{2} = \frac{\lVert u + v\rVert^2 - \lVert u - v\rVert^2}{4}$$
(notice that these formulas are indeed symmetric!)

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law?rq=1) could also be of interest about this.

The interest for optimization is that when the norm is quadratic, the inner product allows to compute easily the derivative of the norm. Indeed,
\begin{align}\frac{\|x+tv\|^2 -\|x\|^2}{t}& =\frac{B(x+tv,x+tv)-B(x,x)}{t} \\ & = 2B(x,v)+tB(v,v),\end{align}and taking the limit $t\to 0$, you see that the inner product gives the directional derivatives and thus the differential of the norm.

Knowing that the norm is quadratic is also very useful in problems like linear regression and least squares, because you can see the problem as "finding the vector in a subspace that is the closest to some data", and then the solution is the orthogonal projection on that subspace.